# Software for tagging arbitrary files

Tags: windows, photos, tags, binary-files

I'd like a program that allows me to tag and organize arbitrary binary files, without having to modify them or move them around. Also, the files could be stored on a local HDD or on a DVD or any other non-connected media. I imagine that such a program would keep a database of file checksums and tags. It'd be great if said program then would let me scan a directory and allow me to move and select files based on what tags they have.

Then I'd be able to do something like this (using photos in this example, but I'd like to do this using any kind of file): When I empty my camera SD-card, I tag all pictures with keywords, and I also tag all the crappy pictures as "crappy" and then remove them. Later, I find a backup of the same SD-card and I'm unsure exactly what it contains. I'd like to be able to quickly check if the pictures in there has been tagged, and also be able to discard any pictures marked as "crappy".

Is there such a program?

Answer (score 1):

One such tool is [www.taggtool.com](http://www.taggtool.com), this works exactly like you describe.

MD5 codes used to pair files with the metadata.

Regards